# Arrow Keys not working, can't access other OS in bootloader

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, bootloader

My Laptop down and right arrow Keys are not working, I checked by loading system setup that it's a hardware issue. Is there, if any, alternative to arrow keys so that I can select the other operating system.
I have a dell inspiron 5537R, i7, 8GB/1TB Laptop and the two OS are Windows 10 and ubuntu 14.04
Edit:: The default bootloader is Ubuntu

Comment: As far as I know Windows 10 OS Select Page allows you to use a mouse/touchpad to select which OS to boot.

Comment: Press and hold shift button at the time of booting.

Comment: The default bootloader is of Ubuntu!!....so mouse doesn't work

Comment: @max Shift button works in case of windows but if I am running ubuntu, then the shift doesn't work!!

Comment: Shift key should work. Better you check this http://askubuntu.com/q/117525/71440

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

Ctrl+B = Left, Ctrl+F = Right(mnemonic: backward/forward)Ctrl+P = Up, Ctrl+N = Down(mnemonic: up/down)Ctrl+A = Home, Ctrl+E = End(mnemonic: A=beginning/end)

Or possibly PgUp and PgDn?